# How to integrate objective C or swift programming code into cordova ios app?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have some objective C code. I need to integrate it into my cordova project.
How can I run that code in my Cordova IOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. But to get you pointed in the right direction:

Open your project in finder and navigate to platforms>ios>[project-name]>Classes.
Here you will find AppDelegate and ViewController files. These are written in objective C. AppDelegate handles a lot of the central processes of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add something specific in ObjectiveC you have to write a plugin. Here's the doc about it : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html
Once you've integrated your new plugin into your cordova app, you just have to execute your native callback from the javascript code. It works the same way as an official plugin.

What exactly do you want to add in ObjectiveC, are you sure that you can't do it from the webView ? (I mean in JS and not as native code)